# Android Build and Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Have these erro when i'm trying to build the  apk to some devices. Have no idea whats going on.

I get that when i build and install apk on device at the first time.

Someone have some tips for that?

[[EDIT]]

Well, after creating a debug key on keystore, i can build and deploy the apk via ADP to the device. But, dont know why, the error just return...

And now, we have other error:

[image]

UPDATE:

**I Fix that issue removing all Android SDK and Android Studio and ReInstall it.**

Answer (score 8):

The problem can be solved by addding the install flags -r -t in the Run/Debug Configuration Dialog like it's showed in the given image
[image]
You can find Run/Debug Configuration Dialog location [here](https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.3/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) according to Jetbrains.
**UPDATE:** Depending on the Android Studio version the Run/Debug Configuration position in the IDE can be slightly different, but always refer Jetbrains to find whatever you are looking for

Comment: what flag mean?

Answer (score 2):

When you've installed an APK from another source, Android Studio warns you before overwriting.

For example, if I've developed an application, uploaded it onto the Google Play Store, downloaded it, then try to re-deploy that same application from Android Studio, I'll get this warning.

It's trying to tell you that the way the package is *[signed](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)* is different; it's warning you that another app might be masquerading as the original.

Comment: Nice... but i'm on development mode, have hard reset the device, and installing directly from the AndroidStudio.

I'll check that...

Comment: Just check to see if your application is already installed on that device. Have you deployed it before from another computer?

Comment: Well, i dont know WHY, but when i created a new keystore, and reinstall the apk, they work! Thanks a lot!

Trying to understand why... 

Have two sdks installed on the machine... the only reason i can imagine that cause this issue is that, and have two debug signatures and the android studio doesnt know how to use... 

But, is working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I Have edited the question, because the error return... and have no reasons why

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are trying to install the application with the same package name.
If you have already downloaded the same application from the play store /app market, then simply uninstall that application and RE-RUN.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you recently switched branch which had different build variants declared in `build.gradle` file and you didn't perform gradle sync.

For example you had `release` and `debug` and then you switched to branch which has `releas`, `deubg` and `staging` variants; your project will still build but while installing apk this error can pop up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely because of your ADB location. You can solve this by toggling the automatic ADB location and choosing the ADB location itself manually

Steps:-

1. Open your emulator from Device Manager in Android Studio
2. Click on the three dots at the right-hand side of your emulator
3. Click on Settings
4. Edit the ADB location to the one located in your system. You can find this usually following this pattern /Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
   5.Then drag and drop your apk to the emulator. It should install now[image: Install APK on Emulator using manual ADB location]