# Error while installing apk: INSTALL PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting error INSTALL PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK while building and installing my apk, after making any changes on the code the app just doesn't install any more on phisical devices. I'm not getting the problem in virtual devices.

The Android Studio log says:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK
Installation failed due to: 'null'
Retry
```

This problem is happening only after updating android studio from v3.2 to v3.5, after that I've updated to v3.5.1 expecting a bug fix, but nothing happened. I've updated several components when I updated my IDE, so I don't know exactly if one of them is the one that caused the problem.

Comment: Related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908389/android-build-and-installation-error-install-parse-failed-not-apk ?  Try removing the app from your phyiscal device first.  I've sometimes found my app listed in the apps list by bundle name (com.yourcompany.application) rather than the application name, so check for that too.

Comment: After uninstalling the app I can install it again with no problem, but if I make any code changes, the problems come back again. In the cited post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908389/android-build-and-installation-error-install-parse-failed-not-apk) the author says the problem was gone after reinstalling the IDE, so i think this could be a bad configuration or maybe a missing component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5), so I tried one of the given solutions, adding the -r and -t flags to the Install flags in the Run/Debug Configuration dialog, and it solved my problem, Run/Debug Configuration dialog can be found [here](https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.3/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) according to Jetbrains

Comment: If you are trying to install the application with the same package name or if you have already downloaded the same application from the play store then uninstall that existing app and try to install it again.