# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK

Tags: java, android

when i debug on physical devices, sometimes i get a error message

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\PROJECT\Hopel\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl780010291.tmp/base.apk'
Retry
```

when i retry , the error disappear and i can bebug normally. i don't know why and how can i fix it?

**have a nice day, everyone!**

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908389/android-build-and-installation-error-install-parse-failed-not-apk) might help.

Comment: thanks you so much!